# Definition of Big-Oh

Tags: algorithm, big-o

g(n) ≤ c × f(n), for every n ≥ n0, for some c and n0, 
is it also true that g(n) ≤ c' × f(n), for every n, and some c'?

I said it's false because the definition of Big-Oh is true since n starts form n0. g(n) cannot go over cf(n) for every n ≥ n0, but g(n) can go over if it's every n making the definition of Big-Oh false.

I wonder if I correctly answered it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plain English explanation of Big O](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o)

Answer (score 1):

Let's look carefully at the given statements:

- `∃ n0 ∃ c≥0 (∀ n ≥ n0) (g(n) ≤ cf(n))` (1)
- `∃ c'≥0     ∀ n       (g(n) ≤ c'f(n)` (2)

// where "∃ means there exists" and "∀ means for all".

So the question is: if (1) is true is (2) also true? To see that this is not the case take `g(n) = 1` and `f(n) = n-100`. You can see that (1) is correct for `n0 = 101` and `c = 1` but for (2)  if you take `n=0` you can't find such `c' ≥0` that `1 ≤ c'*(-100)`. That means that for those `f` and `g` (1) is correct but (2) is not. So you are right.

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot.

Comment: @JayKay9 I'm always happy to help :)